# Naming and embedding functions in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been all through this.  Trying to change the color of a button's background color to a random color on click.  I can't figure out how to place my function in correct JQUERY format.  Help please.

```
$( document ).ready(function getRandomColor() {
    var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);  
    return randomColor;
});
});
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color':getRandomColor()});
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate functions, begin string which set `background-color` with `#`. See [`colors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getRandomColor() {
    var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    return randomColor;
  }

  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).css(
      'background-color', "#" + getRandomColor()
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You were very close, with a few syntax errors.

You need the **#** on the color string.

```
function getRandomColor() {
  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  return "#" + randomColor;
}

$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'background-color': getRandomColor()
  });
});
```